# How to collapse borders in css grid (not table)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid, border

I have this react-tailwind component:

```
{/* <div className='grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(230px,1fr))] border-t border-l border-gray-300 my-4'> */}
      <div className='grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(230px,1fr))] my-4'>
        {productsToRender.map((product, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            onClick={() => console.log(`product [${product.title}] clicked`)}
            // className='flex flex-col justify-between items-center cursor-pointer border-r border-b bg-white border-gray-300'
            className={`flex flex-col justify-between items-center cursor-pointer 
        border-r border-b bg-white border-gray-300`}
            style={{
              borderTop: i % 2 === 0 ? '1px solid #ccc' : 'none',
              borderLeft: i === 0 || i % 2 === 0 ? '1px solid #ccc' : 'none',
            }}
          >
            <img src={product.img_url} alt={product.title} className='w-[13rem]' />
            <div className="flex flex-col p-[1rem]">
              <span className='font-semibold'>{product.title}</span>
              <span style={{
                height: '4rem',
                lineHeight: '20px',
                wordBreak: 'break-all',
                display: '-webkit-box',
                WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                MozBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                msBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                boxOrient: 'vertical',
                WebkitLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                MozLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                msLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                lineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                overflow: 'hidden',
              }}>{product.description}</span>
              <span className='mt-[1rem]'>{formatter.format(product.price)}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

The grid does not have fixed number of columns (thats why `grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(230px,1fr))]` so that the number of columns can change based on the screen).

Now the commented div and className are working correctly as the first div (the grid) only renders border-t and border-l (top and left). While each cell (the third div) renders border-r and border-b (right and bottom).

This works as long as the first row is filled with cells. Once there are less cells needed to fill the row. the bottom-t would span the entire width (and not only those needed to cover only used ones). Is there is relatively simple way (not a crazy calculations and functions for 100 lines) to make correct borders (not duplicated and covering only what they should cover - the only needed number of cells)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider:

1. Having borders on all sides for each grid item.
2. Using `-1px` for `margin-top` and `margin-left` on each grid item to draw subsequent borders on top of each other, akin to border collapsing.
3. Applying `padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 1px` to the grid parent to offset the `-1px` `margin`s for the top-most and left-most items.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
const NUM_OF_DESC_LINES = 1;
  
function Grid({ products: productsToRender }) {
  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(230px,1fr))] my-4 pt-px pl-px'>
        {productsToRender.map((product, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            onClick={() => console.log(`product [${product.title}] clicked`)}
            className={`flex flex-col justify-between items-center cursor-pointer bg-white border border-gray-300 -ml-px -mt-px`}
          >
            <img src={product.img_url} alt={product.title} className='w-[13rem]' />
            <div className="flex flex-col p-[1rem]">
              <span className='font-semibold'>{product.title}</span>
              <span style={{
                height: '4rem',
                lineHeight: '20px',
                wordBreak: 'break-all',
                display: '-webkit-box',
                WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                MozBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                msBoxOrient: 'vertical',
                boxOrient: 'vertical',
                WebkitLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                MozLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                msLineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                lineClamp: NUM_OF_DESC_LINES,
                overflow: 'hidden',
              }}>{product.description}</span>
              <span className='mt-[1rem]'>{formatter.format(product.price)}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}

function App() {
  const product = {
    title: 'Foo',
    img_url: 'https://picsum.photos/208/208',
    description: 'Foo',
    price: 42,
  };

  return (
    <div className="space-y-4">
      <Grid products={Array(2).fill(product)} />
      <Grid products={Array(10).fill(product)} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, what the f. It works but I have no idea how. Can you please elaborate? :D

Comment: Have borders on all sides for each grid item for every side. The `-1px` for `margin-top` and `margin-left` on each grid item draws subsequent borders on top of each other, akin to border collapsing. The `padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 1px` to the grid parent offsets the `-1px` `margin`s for the top-most and left-most items.

Comment: So your solution works for the original grid. I have now posted a slighty different grid (with the same problem). Could you please show a solution for that as well? I tried to apply the classes as from the original but didnt work this time

Comment: The new code seems to work fine [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuc2dL0s/). You should consider posting a new question instead of editing an existing question for additional questions.